# Submit Form several times with JQuery Ajax without reload the page

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

i have a form and can submit it one time with Ajax. As response comes a form too and it replaces the old. But when i then press the submit Button the form doesn't submit with Ajax and goes with the normal method. Why?
Here my JQuery-Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ajax_form').submit(function(e) {
            var form = $('#ajax_form');
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post('game/write.php', data, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#power').replaceWith(response);
            });
            return false;
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

The form:

```
<div id="power">
<div class="span4">
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="4" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="5" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="8" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
</div>
<div class="span4">
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="6" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img  src="images/null.png"></button></form>
    <form action="game/write.php" id="ajax_form" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="9" name="button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><img src="images/null.png"></button></form>
</div>
```

This for comes also back, only the Buttoncolors are different.

Comment: why u using from tag like this ? what is your task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need event delegation -

```
$(document).on('submit','#ajax_form',function(e) {
```

Try this -

```
$(document).on('submit','#ajax_form',function(e) {
   var form = $('#ajax_form');
   var data = form.serialize();
   $.post('game/write.php', data, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $('#power').replaceWith(response);
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you help me again? I have 9 forms with the id ajax_form. When i press the submit button of any form, the first form would be submit. But i want that when you press the submit button only the form where the submit button belongs to will submit.

Answer (score -1):

**event.preventDefault()**

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Now updated your code like bellow

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {


  $('#ajax_form').click(function(event) {//use click instead of submit 

     event.preventDefault() // then use even.preventDefault()

    var form = $('#ajax_form');
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.post('game/write.php', data, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#power').replaceWith(response);
    });
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

add event.preventDefault() [ If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. ]

Comment: He already has `return false;`, that's the same thing in this case. If it was a matter of the form submitting OP wouldn't be able to submit the form once with ajax.

Comment: @Musa Even when returning false at the end, the JS will run then return false, meaning that the form `action` will still be called, no? His code will run quick so we won't actually see changes but if was a slow code, the action would work first and redirect to the page before the js arrives the `return false`. Anyways I think Mohamad answer nailed it. Since OP code was on ready, it would not delegate to the new piece of code since is inside doc.ready thus running for that dom only..